# How to specify an "id" for a path in Nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

suppose this is my data

```
data = [
         {
         "key": "Series1",
         "values": [ [ 1125409600000 , 0] , [ 1228088000000 , 50]]
         },
         {
         "key": "Series2",
         "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 10] , [ 1028088000000 , 50]]
         }
 ]
```

I am using Nvd3 to draw a line chart. So based on the data given above I should have two lines.

```
 nv.addGraph(function() {
     var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();
     d3.select('#chart svg')
       .datum(data)
       .transition().duration(500)
       .call(chart);
      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
      return chart;
});
```

I can easily do this and my code works. After drawing the chart, each line on the chart is path in the DOM. I am trying to assign each KEY value as an id of the corresponding path. For example, after drawing the graph I want to have something like this

```
  <path id="Series1" ..... >
  <path id="Series2" ..... >
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: group containing a path has the desired id

Comment: @baklazan Thanks for the reply. I am not sure whether I understood your answer. Group containing a path has an id which I am not sure where it is coming from. I would like to assign an id to the path so that I can select the path later based on my own logics.

Answer (score 0):

As @baklazan states in his comment, the group around the path has a **class** of `nv-series-0`, `nv-series-1`, etc...  If you can just use that and get the corresponding path like:

```
var series1Path = d3.select('.nv-series-0>path');
```

If you really want to `id` them:

```
d3.select('.nv-series-0>path')
  .attr('id','Series1);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Let me clarify my goal. I have a csv file that I am reading it and drawing the line chart. Each line is showing a soccer player and I would like to assign each name to a group containing the path. So I can refer to that specific line later and highlight it or etc. In d3 I could assign it while drawing the lines however nvd3 does not give me that access while I am drawing the line. Of course I can retrieve '.nv-series-0>path' but I do not know which player it refers to.

Comment: @BahadorSaket, the only thing that comes to mind, is that `nvd3` won't re-order your data, so you could do it by index.  Search the data, find the index of that players name, then `d3.select('.nv-series-'+ index + '>path');`  I don't know of anyway to get `nvd3` to id or class your series while drawing.